# curl_init conflict with wordpress on twitter oAuth

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the [Abraham Williams twitter library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) on my Wordpress development. I am at the stage of validating everything and the `oAuth.php` has produced a potential error on the theme check plugin required for Themeforest.

```
WARNING: curl_init was found in the file includes/resources/twitter/twitteroauth.php possible file operations.
```

and

```
WARNING: curl_exec was found in the file includes/resources/twitter/twitteroauth.php possible file operations.
```

This is in the following function

```
function http($url, $method, $postfields = NULL) {
    $this->http_info = array();
    $ci = curl_init();
    /* Curl settings */
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->useragent);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->connecttimeout);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->ssl_verifypeer);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, array($this, 'getHeader'));
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

    switch ($method) {
      case 'POST':
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        if (!empty($postfields)) {
          curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        }
        break;
      case 'DELETE':
        curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
        if (!empty($postfields)) {
          $url = "{$url}?{$postfields}";
        }
    }

    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ci);
    $this->http_code = curl_getinfo($ci, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $this->http_info = array_merge($this->http_info, curl_getinfo($ci));
    $this->url = $url;
    curl_close ($ci);
    return $response;
  }
```

Does anyone know a fix for this?

### NOTE

From further reading it is recommended to use

```
wp_remote_request()
```

Any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an error, it's a warning.

It also doesn't look like it coming from PHP since it does not contain the line and PHP warnings are spelled `Warning` not `WARNING`.

This looks like a security feature of Wordpress to tell you curl executions in plugins and scripts.

You should open a case here: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/theme-check

Comment: Yeah I know its not a error and is generated from a plugin called themecheck which checks against recomendations before a theme is submitted. It won't be accepted unless this is fixed. I am looking fro a alternative/fix. :)

Comment: Looks like yet another prove for wordpress' bad code :/ I googled a little bit but could not find any case regarding curl..

Comment: @DanFromGermany This isn't a WordPress thing, as such. ThemeForest (who aren't part of WordPress, they just sell themes) auto-check submissions to their theme directory for common problems. In this case, it looks like [they prefer the use of the WordPress builtin `wp_remote_get()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981283/curl-init-conflict-with-wordpress-on-twitter-oauth) to cURL, but I couldn't say why. @AlbaClan, you may be better asking in the ThemeForest forums.